# Out of Memory Error in Scikit-learn MultinomialNB

Tags: scikit-learn, scikits

In order to run NB classifier in about 400 MB of text data i need to use vectorizer.

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=2)
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_data)
```

But it is giving out of memory error. I am using Linux64 an python 64 bit version. How does people work through Vectorization process in Scikit for large data set (text)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ParseData.py", line 234, in <module>
    main()
  File "ParseData.py", line 211, in main
    classifier = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "/home/pratibha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 313, in fit
    Y = labelbin.fit_transform(y)
  File "/home/pratibha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 408, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "/home/pratibha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py", line 272, in transform
    neg_label=self.neg_label)
  File "/home/pratibha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py", line 394, in label_binarize
    Y = np.zeros((len(y), len(classes)), dtype=np.int)
```

Edited (ogrisel): I changed the title from "Out of Memory Error in Scikit Vectorizer" to "Out of Memory Error in Scikit-learn MultinomialNB" to make it more descriptive of the actual problem.

Comment: The traceback does not seem to involve the vectorization step but the label extraction from the y variable when calling `MultinomialNB().fit(X_train, y_train)`. What is in your `y_train` variables? What is the shape of this datastructure?

Comment: Hi Orgisel, the original shape of X_train is 6MX6M and y_train is 6Mx43K. I tried to trim down and took only a subset of X_train which is 400Kx6M and ytrain 400Kx43k

Comment: You are saying that y_train is a sparse indicator matrix (with 0 and 1 labels) to classify 6M data points in 43000 possible classes? I am afraid that even if the label preprocessing code is fixed, MultinomialNB is using a dense representation and will never be able to store the parameters for that many classes.

Comment: Hi Ogrisel, Thanks for the inputs. You are correct y_train is the sparse matrix. Can you please let me know what label propagation code does? ( I have heard this term many time but never understood). Also what are my options for such huge dataset. Any other classifier SVC will work?

Comment: I did not speak about label propagation but label preprocessing, basically the line 394 of sklearn/preprocessing/label.py that allocates a dense n_samples x n_classes numpy arrays that takes all your memory. There is ongoing work to fix that in scikit-learn master but anyway as far as I know we don't have a good solution to fit multi-class or multi-label models with such a high cardinality (43k classes) in scikit-learn right now. I think this is stiff an open research problem: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/manik/events/XC13/index.html

Comment: Maybe you could do a PCA of the target labels, then cast your classification problem as a multi-output regression problem in the reduced label PCA space, and then decode regressors output by looking for the nearest class encoding in the label PCA space.

Comment: Hi Orgisel, Nice idea. BTW it is a problem of tag prediction. I will try this.

Comment: I learned this trick from Mathieu Blondel by I had no opportunity to try it myself so far. Please feel free to report you results back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me summarize the outcome of the discussion in the comments:

- The label preprocessing machinery used internally in many scikit-learn classifiers does not scale well memory wise w.r.t. the number of classes. This is a known issue and there is [ongoing work](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/2458) to tackle it.
- The MultinomialNB class it-self will probably not be suitable to classify in a label space with cardinality 43K even if the label preprocessing limitation is fixed.

To address the large cardinality classification problem you could try:

- fit binary `SGDClassifier(loss='log', penalty='elasticnet')` instances on columns of `y_train` converted as numpy arrays independently, then call `clf.sparsify()` and finally wrap those sparse models as a final one-vs-rest classifier (or rank predictions of the binary classifier by proba). Dependending on the value of the regularizer parameter alpha you might get sparse models that are small enough to fit in memory. You can also try to do the same with `LogisticRegression`, that is something like:

  clf_label_i = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1').fit(X_train, y_train[:, label_i].toarray()).sparsify()
- alternatively try to do a PCA of the target labels `y_train`, then cast your classification problem as a multi-output regression problem in the reduced label PCA space, and then decode the regressor's output by looking for the nearest class encoding in the label PCA space.

You can also have a look at 
[Block Coordinate Descent Algorithms for Large-scale Sparse Multiclass Classification](http://www.mblondel.org/code/mlj2013/) implemented in [lightning](https://github.com/mblondel/lightning) but I am not sure it suitable for label cardinality 43K either.

Comment: Thanks Ogrisel, Very well comprehended